# Is it possible to have a struct within an Event?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, events

I have something like this in solidity:

```
struct Bid {
   ...
}
event BidEvent(Bid bid)
```

but when I try to read this event in Javascript, there's no data inside that I can access — no `bid` variable, none of the things inside it, nothing at all really.

Does this mean `struct`s can't be put inside `event`s?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using a struct inside an event and receive compilation errors. You need to pass specific value type variables (address, uint, etc) into the event and then you could use these to access the full Bid struct object when the event gets triggered if you need the entire object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `Zero-Error` Solidity Smart Contract code to use `struct` with `event` & `function parameter` :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
contract aakash4dev{
    struct datas{
        uint a;
        string b;
    }
    event DataBro(datas dd);
    function putdata(datas memory d) public {
       emit DataBro(d);     
    }
}
```

put data like this: `[4444,"aakash 4 dev"]` on [RemixIDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/)
[image: aakash4dev]

if you use `Web3.js` instade of RemixIDE use `call()` function like this: `myContract.methods.putdata([1234,"some string"]).call()`

web3JS doc: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

if Python: Web3Py docs: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#methods

happy codings !! ‍